# SQLite select multiple foreign keys to one row

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to set up a high scores board for a game I'm making. On the board, I'm using foreign keys to two other boards, players and weapons. Each score stores the four weapons the player used on that run. The tables are set up like this:

```
Scores
id|playerid|score|weapon0id|weapon1id|weapon2id|weapon3id

Players
id|name

Weapons
id|name
```

I want to select multiple rows from the scores table with ids replaced by the appropriate names. I'm able to get the correct player name and one weapon using this statement:

```
SELECT scoreID, Players.playerName, scoreVal,
    Weapons.weaponLabel, scoreW1, scoreW2, scoreW3
FROM Scores, Players, Weapons
WHERE Players.playerID = scorePlayer AND Weapons.weaponID = scoreW0
```

Everywhere I've looked shows that to be the best way to get a value from a row referred to by a foreign key. It works fine for the player name, but there seems to be no way to expand this to fill in multiple weapon names at once. Using an OR with the remaining weapons or using weaponID IN (w0,w1,w2,w3) seems to get one row for each weapon, not one row with each weapon in the appropriate spot.

Is there any way to get the correct weapon names just using the select statement? Or will I need to have extra code loop through and replace each weapon id with the correct name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is questionable: `weapon0..n` will likely lead to nothing but difficult queries like this. The queries will also have to be de-normalized - e.g. one join *per* `weapon0..n`.

Anyway, the query is wrong and will return *many more rows than desired* because it uses the form `FROM a,b` which implies a CROSS JOIN between a and b and there is not appropriate selectors in the WHERE to make it an equi-join. Try to use a normal (INNER) `JOIN` and `ON` to make each join more apparent:

```
SELECT s.scoreID, p.playerName, s.scoreVal,
    w0.weaponLabel as w0Label,
    w1.weaponLabel as w1Label
    -- etc
FROM Scores s
JOIN Players p ON p.id = s.playerID
JOIN Weapons w0 ON w0.weaponID = s.scoreW0
JOIN Weapons w1 ON w1.weaponID = s.scoreW1
-- etc, ick!!!
```

By now it should become apparent why the de-normalized data is icky!
*Each column* must be joined with a *different relation* (w0, w1, etc).

Comment: I wasn't aware selecting from multiple tables did a cross-join, thanks. (This is my first SQL project) For this game, there are always exactly four weapons being used by the player. I had assumed that it would be easier with that assumption to just do things four times. I'll use that example for now, and look a bit more into normalization. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have to create a looping procedure to get all the denormalized columns in one row per unique set, in your case player, weaponlabel.